# Split file using empty line space in shell script and store in array

Tags: shell

I am trying to split a myfile.txt with a empty line as delimiter and store each value in an array.

```
fruit=mango, lime, orange,grape

car=nissan,
ford,
toyota,
honda

country=russia, england, ireland,
usa,
mexico,australia

colors=green, orange, purple, white,
yellow
```

I wrote following script

```
while IFS='\n' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    if [[ $line != "" ]]; then
        arr+=("$line")
        echo "File Content : $line"
    fi
done < myfile.txt
```

The problem I am having is for country it read like this

```
File Content : country=russia, england, ireland
File Content : usa,
File Content : mexico,australia
```

I want that to be printed as

```
File Content : country=russia, england, ireland, usa,mexico,australia
```

Can you someone help me to tune my script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you speak to "arrays", this should be tagged not just "shell", but for a specific shell (like bash) with array support. Baseline POSIX sh does not support arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare -A content=( )                    # create an empty associative array, "content"
curr_key=                                 # and a blank "key" variable

while read -r line; do
  [[ $line ]] || { curr_key=; continue; } # on a blank input line, reset the key
  if [[ $line = *=* ]]; then              # if we have an equal sign...
    curr_key=${line%%=*}                  # ...then use what's left of it as the key
    content[$curr_key]=${line#*=}         # ...and what's right of it as initial value
  elif [[ $curr_key ]]; then              # on a non-blank line with no equal sign...
    content[$curr_key]+=$line             # ...append the current line to the current value
  fi
done

declare -p content                        # print what we've found
```

Given your input file, and run with a bash 4.0 or newer, the above prints as output (modified for readable formatting only):

```
declare -A content='([car]="nissan,ford,toyota,honda"
                     [colors]="green, orange, purple, white,yellow"
                     [fruit]="mango, lime, orange,grape" 
                     [country]="russia, england, ireland,usa,mexico,australia" )'
```

If you then want to iterate over members of a category, you can do so as follows:

```
IFS=', ' read -r -a cars <<<"${content[car]}"
for car in "${cars[@]}"; do
  echo "Found a car: $car"
done
```

Comment: I ran this by modifying done < $fileLocation
echo ${#content[@]} 
echo ${content[@]}

here is the output I got

1
green, orange, purple, white,yellow

I am using bash version 4.2

Comment: It didn't work in my mac, but worked fine in linux machine.

Comment: MacOS doesn't ship bash 4.2 -- if you're using a copy from macports, be sure you modify your shebang, either to point to it directly or to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (with your PATH having 4.2 first).

Comment: BTW, quotes are important. `<"$fileLocation"`; `printf '%s\n' "${content[@]}"`; etc. (Suggesting `printf` there because with `echo` passed multiple arguments, you can't distinguish between element boundaries and whitespace within an individual element); etc.

Comment: @Moogly, ...getting only `green, orange, purple, white, yellow` as output means that your bash doesn't have associative arrays, ie. that it's 3.x not 4.x, so it keeps overwriting the first array entry (index 0, because when "fruit" or "car" or "country" or "colors" is used in numeric context -- like a non-associative array index -- it evaluates to 0 unless there's a variable by those names with a numeric value).

Comment: Thank you very much I figured out the problem, I am having sh(3.2 version) and bash(4.2 version) I changed my  script into .bash and executed from bash console it works fine. Like you said I have added the bash location to PATH.

Comment: The file extension (`.bash` vs `.sh`) doesn't matter -- in fact, it's good practice not to give executable scripts extensions at all; it's only the shebang that makes a difference (and using extension-less names means that a shebang change is hidden behind an abstraction layer, so you can rewrite a script in a new language -- or even replace it with a compiled executable -- change its shebang appropriately, and nothing calling or invoking it needs to change at all).

Comment: ...that said, when bash is called with the name "sh", it actually runs in POSIX compatibility mode, turning off a number of features, so even if `/bin/sh` *were* provided by bash 4.2, it still wouldn't work for the above script.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest an alternative solution to fix the format and have a simpler logic to deal with lines.

```
$ awk -v RS= '{gsub(",\n",",")}1' file
```

results

```
fruit=mango, lime, orange,grape
car=nissan,ford,toyota,honda
country=russia, england, ireland,usa,mexico,australia
colors=green, orange, purple, white,yellow
```

you can add empty lines in between by adding the option `-v ORS="\n\n"` as well.